# What is wrong with my simple label constraint that it's asking me to define compression constants?

Tags: ios, uiview, uilabel, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'm trying to set up a simple UITableViewCell with Auto Layout so that it automatically detects the height of the cell. The cell simply has two labels, one on top of the other.

The top one is positioned away from the top, left and right, while the bottom one is positioned away from the bottom and aligned to the left and right side of the upper label with a space set between them.

```
                       | 20px
- 20px -              Label One     - 20px -
                       | 20px
- Align left-         Label Two      - Align right-
                       | 20px
```

However it complains that I need to add compression constants to the constraints and I get the yellow warning lines. What am I doing wrong? How is this not sufficiently detailed?

**Example project:** http://cl.ly/3q3H1M1X0c0b

Comment: I don't think you're doing anything wrong, I get the same warnings when I do this. Interestingly, if I make the same UI in code instead of in IB, I get no warnings. You only need to adjust one of the compression constants up by one to get rid of the warning. I think this is probably a bug.

Comment: How many lines do the labels have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that `UILabel` has an intrinsic content size (the exact size of its text) and it would prefer to stay that size at all times. So try to constrain its position instead of its size.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing, there are no size constraints.